# Parse an XML object from a column into multiple rows and allow the next XML object after last row

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

This is a little hard to explain in words so I create an example spreadsheet to show you the issue:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zqqVOWkp8dw87lhr05NSuiE9ezb84CFtQphwrpZxpes/

I have an export from a system with a list of XML files.
I need to parse each XML into rows and each row needs to have the ID of the project.

The issue is that when parsing the XML, it can have up to 12 rows in it. Sometimes it will only have 1, sometime it will have 12 or anything in between.

I need this to work based on a formula that will account for the dynamic number of rows per XML file.
It sounds like I need to count the rows needed for each xml and then adjust where the second XML file starts in a secondary list.

The XML and the Project ID is the information that's known from the start.

Comment: Would you be willing to use an Apps Script custom formula for this?

Comment: You are right, a custom formula using apps script could accomplish what I'm looking for so yes.

Comment: I'm getting `Imported content is empty` when using `IMPORTXML` on the provided URLs. Seems like there is a problem with the files you want to import data from?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes. that's due to the way that website and google sheet caches the data. Couldn't find a free website that can host an XML file without this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is the number of activities in each project then

```
=importxml($j$3,"count(//ActivityDetails)")
```

would output `3` for the url in that cell in your sheet, and that's the number of rows you need for that entry.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I then "paste" the second XML from Column A  into Column J exactly 3 rows after the first XML and also maintain the formulas in Column L-N? It's almost like I need an array formula in the first row that can take care of the entire row. Array formula is not supported with importxml

Comment: also, not sure what's up with google sheets. It imports the XML file once and then refuses to import it again. Maybe it's the file server site.